# Path in a Heap takes too long time

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

This is a question from oj [PAT](http://www.patest.cn/contests/mooc-ds2015spring/05-%E6%A0%916)

> Insert a sequence of given numbers into an initially empty min-heap H. Then for any given index i, you are supposed to print the path from H[i] to the root.

However, my code always time out, i.e, it takes too long time. How to solve it?

```
main()
{
    int i,*a,n,m,k,data;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    a[0]=-10001;  //
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&data);
        heapAdjust(a,data);
    }   

    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&k);
        printf("%d",a[k]);
        k=k/2;
    while(1)
    {
        printf(" %d",a[k]);
        if(k==1)
            break;
        k=k/2;
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    free(a);
}
void heapAdjust(int a[],int data) // make heap
{
    static int size=0;
    int i;
    i=++size;
    for(;a[i/2]>data;i=i/2)
        a[i]=a[i/2];
    a[i]=data;
}
```

Comment: If the root is at `a[1]`, then you'll need to make your array size `n+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into an infinite loop because `k` becomes zero at some point.

Try changing the `break` condition inside the `while(1)` loop from `k == 1` to `k <= 1` and see if that helps.

Comment: In fact, `k` will go to 0 if the input is `1` (i.e. they ask for the path from the root). Easily solved if you replace that `while(1)` with a `while(k > 0)`. Simplifies the code, too.